# Fix elements so only the one hovered over extends?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a top menu consisting of four div's: Home, Menu, Order, and Review. I have set it so that each div extends 100px when hovered over. Everything worked fine at this point. I then added some words and an image within each of the div's extended area. Now whenever I hover over any of the div's, it extends, but it carry's the rest of the div's with it. I want it so that only the div I am hovering over will extend and the rest will remain where they were. Here's the html:

```
<div class="TopNav">
            <a href="file:///C:/Users/Justin/SkyDrive/Documents/Websites/Snack%20Shack%202/SS2.html"><div class="Home">
                <h4>Home</h4> <br><br>
                <p>Learn about us!</p>
                <img class="Hamburger" src="http://i.imgur.com/0htcpM2.png" title="source: imgur.com" />
            </div></a>

            <a href="file:///C:/Users/Justin/SkyDrive/Documents/Websites/Snack%20Shack%202/SS2%20Menu.html"><div class="Menu">
                <h4>Menu</h4>
            </div></a>

            <a href="file:///C:/Users/Justin/SkyDrive/Documents/Websites/Snack%20Shack%202/SS2%20Order.html"><div class="Order">
                <h4>Order</h4>
            </div></a>

            <a href="file:///C:/Users/Justin/SkyDrive/Documents/Websites/Snack%20Shack%202/SS2%20Review.html"><div class="Review">
                <h4>Review</h4>
            </div></a>
        </div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.Home:hover, .Menu:hover, .Order:hover, .Review:hover{
    height: 150px;
}

.Home, .Menu, .Order, .Review {
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.Home p, .Menu p, .Order p, .Review p {
    text-align:right;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    right:2px;
    bottom:5px;
}

.Home h4, .Menu h4, .Order h4, .Review h4 {
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    bottom:5px;
    font-family:Garamond;
}

.Hamburger {
    height:40px;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
    top:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: i think you need to share you html to get help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `vertical-align: top;` to `.Home, .Menu, .Order, .Review`

`inline-block` element aligns to the `bottom` of the highest element by taking `vertical-align: baseline;` as default but you can `align` it to the `top` by adding `vertical-align:top`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hsj2ebc2/1/